# find the volume of the triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

use a triple integral to find the volume of the sold with the cylinder 
  $  x^2 +  y^2 = 9 $ and between the planes $z =1$ and $x +z$ =5

can we find it using cylindrical coordinates ?

Comment: Spherical is a bad idea.  Cylindrical will do better.

Comment: @B. Goddard Please answer it .

Comment: No one is going to do your homework for you.  If you're too lazy to even attempt the problem, don't expect us to be ambitious about it.

Comment: No its not a home work . It was a paper question . But i am finding that i did it in the right way in the paper

Comment: The way i did it in a paper is the limits are theta from 0 to 2π , r from 0 to 3 , and z from 1 to rcos(theta) +z .    And the theta is outer integral then the r and the z was the first integral .

Comment: @ _B. Goddard . Check my commet . Is it the true way to solve it ?

Comment: The volume can be calculated geometrically.  Why are you using a triple integral?  The answer is $36\pi.$  Is that what your integral gave you?

Comment: You have only to correct the limits for $z$: it runs from $1$ to $5 -r\cos\theta$

Comment: The question was to find the volume using triple integral .

Comment: Yes 5 - rcos(theta). Sorry

Comment: If you want someone to validate your work, you should post your work in the question and ask if it is correct.